# What should I use to save an image in database

Tags: php, mysql

What should I use to save an image in the database. In what type I have to use to store and retrieve the image in PHP and MySQL.

Comment: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/blob.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Rule of thumb is you shouldn't be storing images in the database. Blob is available but is pretty crappy.

What you should be doing is storing the binary file on the filesystem which is many times faster than a database and in the database just store a path or link or file name and have the application load the image from the path instead.

This allows you to easily implement stuff like cdn's or san storage etc for static files. It even allows you to use something like lighttpd to display the static content images rather than apache.

https://blogs.oracle.com/manveen/entry/blob_vs_file_system_storage gives a little more information but there's plenty of stats and data on the web about the disadvantages of blobs

Comment: Additional more indepth paper http://research.microsoft.com/apps/pubs/default.aspx?id=64525

Answer (score 0):

use `BLOB` Datatype which means *Binary Large Object*

- [BLOB](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/blob.html)

Answer (score 0):

BLOB's may be slower than file storage, but it is much easier to copy, backup, and restore a single database file than it is to manage/maintain images in a file structure.

I also recommend storing the images in their own dedicated database (store the properties/tag information in a separate database).

Comment: I tink its not much more complicated to download files. Actually, for me it seems easier.

Comment: no its not. tar -cf /imagefolder/ imagebackup.tar something like that anyway set it as a cron for automated backups. also much easier to backup to something like s3 for example using duplicity without causing the load on the db server of doing a mysqldump. couple that with the lack of performance degredation of the db server its self as its db size grows from image storage.

Answer (score 0):

Simple & optimized option is to upload the image on the server and store the string of "url of the image" in database.

Incase, you want to store actual image file only, then use Blob datatype.

Answer (score -1):

Its a very bad idea to store images in database. Database is determined to save a little pieces of information - not images or files. You have HDD on that purpose.
Instead, you should save image on disk and save its filename in database. Like that:

```
$name = uniqid();
file_put_contents($name.".png",$image_data);
mysql_query("INSERT INTO `images` (image) VALUES ('$name.png')") or die(mysql_error());
```

If you really insist on saving images in DB use [BLOB](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/blob.html).