# need to insert image in database and retrieve it in php and mysql

Tags: php, mysql, content-management-system, phpmyadmin

i am new to php to developing simple content management system i have a field like  menu, position, visible,  img_des, content, information_id .. it almost all working correctly now i need to insert image field to that . i have a separate file for forms and new page creation 
now the following code

```
  if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {                   
  $errors = array();
```

// clean up data before putting in the database

```
$information_id = mysql_prep($_GET['info']);
$menu = trim(mysql_prep($_POST['menu']));  // cut out whitespace for menu

$position = mysql_prep($_POST['position']);
$visible = mysql_prep($_POST['visible']);
$image = mysql_prep($_POST['image']);
$img_des = mysql_prep($_POST['img_des']);
$content = mysql_prep($_POST['content']);

 if(empty($errors)){
 $query = "INSERT INTO pages (
 menu, position, visible, img_des, content, information_id
 ) VALUES (
 '{$menu}', {$position}, {$visible},'{$img_des}', '{$content}',  {$information_id}
    )";
 if ($result = mysql_query($query, $connection))    {
 $message = "The new page was created successfully";
 $new_page_id = mysql_insert_id();  
 redirect_to("content.php?page={$new_page_id}");
 } else {
 $message = "The page failed to create";

 }
 ?>
```

before img_des i want to insert image. what type i have i have to use and what code i have to  put to insert and retrieve image.

Comment: mysql_query has been deprecated, please use PDO http://www.php.net/manual/fr/function.mysql-query.php

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't be storing images in the database. Save the image on the server and save a link to the files location in the database.

see this question for more information: [What should I use to save a image in database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14774425/what-should-i-use-to-save-a-image-in-database)

Comment: I disagree here. Saving images in database may be slower but have some benefits like fine grained access control and data centralization (wich is very important to build [12-factor](http://12factor.net/) compliant apps). So this really is a matter of needs.

Comment: Yes, @hugo_leonardo you do have a point, but considering he is building a simple CMS I thought this would be an easier solution for him. I agree, if more control is required over the images, use a different technique.

Answer (score -1):

```
  try this code.


<?php


        $images_arr = array();
            //This is the directory where images will be saved
        $target_dir = "uploads/";
        $target = $target_dir.$_FILES['photo']['name'];

            //$target = $target . basename( $_FILES['photo']['name']);

            //This gets all the other information from the form
        $name=$_POST['nameMember'];
        $bandMember=$_POST['bandMember'];
        $pic=($_FILES['photo']['name']);
        $about=$_POST['aboutMember'];
        $bands=$_POST['otherBands'];


            // Connects to your Database
        mysql_connect("Localhost", "remote", "remote123") or die(mysql_error()) ;
        mysql_select_db("test") or die(mysql_error()) ;

            //Writes the information to the database
        mysql_query("INSERT INTO dbProfiles (nameMember,bandMember,photo,aboutMember,otherBands)
        VALUES ('$name', '$bandMember', '$pic', '$about', '$bands')") ;

        //Writes the photo to the server
        if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['photo']['tmp_name'], $target)){

                //Tells you if its all ok
            echo "The file ". $target_dir.$_FILES['photo']['name']. " has been uploaded, and your information has been added to the directory";
            $images_arr[] = $target;
        }
        else {

            //Gives and error if its not
            echo "Sorry, there was a problem uploading your file.";
        }

?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
        <link rel="icon" href="http://www.thesoftwareguy.in/favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon" />
                <!--iOS/android/handheld specific -->
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <meta name="description" content="Upload multiple images create thumbnails and save path to database with php and mysql">
        <meta name="keywords" content="php, mysql, thumbnail,upload image, check mime type">
        <meta name="author" content="Shahrukh Khan">
        <title>Upload multiple images create thumbnails and save path to database with php and mysql </title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" type="text/css" />
        <style>
             .files{height: 30px; margin: 10px 10px 0 0;width: 250px; }
            .add{ font-size: 14px; color: #EB028F; border: none; }
            .rem a{ font-size: 14px; color: #f00; border: none; }
            .submit{width: 110px; height: 30px; background: #6D37B0; color: #fff;text-align: center;}
        </style>
        <script src="jquery-1.9.0.min.js"></script>
        <script>
            $(document).ready(function() {
                $(".add").click(function() {
                $('<div><input class="files" name="user_files[]" type="file" ><span class="rem" ><a href="javascript:void(0);" >Remove</span></div>').appendTo(".contents");

                });
                $('.contents').on('click', '.rem', function() {
                $(this).parent("div").remove();
                });

            });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form name="f1" action="index.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">  
            <input type="hidden" name="image_form_submit" value="1"/>
                <div id="container">
                    <div id="body">
                        <div class="mainTitle" >Upload multiple images create thumbnails and save path to database with php and mysql</div>
                        <div class="height20"></div>
                        <article>
                            <div class="height20"></div>
                            <div style="width: 380px; margin: 0 auto;">
                                <h3 style="text-align: center;">Image will be resized to 100px X 100px </h3>

                                <p>Please Enter the Band Members Name.</p>
                                <p> Band Member or Affiliates Name:</p>
                                <input type="text" name="nameMember"/>
                                <p>
                                     Please Enter the Band Members Position. Example:Drums.
                                </p>
                                 <p>
                                    Band Position:
                                 </p>
                                <input type="text" name="bandMember"/>
                                <p>
                                    Please Upload a Photo of the Member in gif or jpeg format. The file name should be named after the Members name. If the same file name is uploaded twice it will be overwritten! Maxium size of File is 35kb.
                                </p>
                                <p>
                                    Photo:
                                </p>
                                <input type="hidden" name="size" value="350000">
                                <input type="file" name="photo"> 
                            <p>
                                Please Enter any other information about the band member here.
                            </p>
                            <p>
                                 Other Member Information:
                            </p>
                            <textarea rows="10" cols="35" name="aboutMember">
                            </textarea>
                             <p>
                                 Please Enter any other Bands the Member has been in.
                             </p>
                            <p>
                                     Other Bands:
                            </p>
                                <input type="text" name="otherBands" size=30 />
                            <br/>
                            <br/>
                                <input TYPE="submit" name="upload" title="Add data to the Database" value="Add Member"/>




                        </div>
                        <table class="bordered">
                         <?php
          // fetch all records
          $sql = "SELECT * FROM dbProfiles WHERE 1 "; ?>
          <?php
         $sql="SELECT * FROM dbProfiles";
 $result_set=mysql_query($sql);
 while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result_set))
 {
  ?>
        <tr>
       <td><p><?php echo $row['nameMember'] ?>"</p></td>
        <td><img src="uploads/<?php echo $row['photo'] ?>" width="200px" height="200px;"/><p><?php echo $row['nameMember'] ?>"</p></td>
        </tr>
        <?php
 }
 ?>
 </table>

                    </article>
                </div>

            </div>
            <div class="height10"></div>

    </form>

  </body>
</html>
<?php

function errorMessage($str) {
  return '<div style="width:50%; margin:0 auto; border:2px solid #F00;padding:2px; color:#000; margin-top:10px; text-align:center;">' . $str . '</div>';
}

function successMessage($str) {
  return '<div style="width:50%; margin:0 auto; border:2px solid #06C;padding:2px; color:#000; margin-top:10px; text-align:center;">' . $str . '</div>';
}
?>
```